# Monaca（Onsen UI）で左右にスライディングメニュー表示した場合のスワイプで閉じた時の挙動について

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

スライディングメニューを左右に配置した場合、
左側をスワイプ操作で閉じるときは問題なくスムーズなのですが、
右側をスワイプ操作で閉じようとすると、
左側のスライディングメニューが開いてしまいます。

例）
http://databasefaq.com/index.php/answer/103174/onsen-ui-how-to-implement-two-slide-menu-on-both-sides-of-a-page-in-onsen-ui

右側スライディングメニューをスワイプ操作で左側同様スムーズに閉じる
（左側スライディングメニューが開かないようにスワイプで閉じる）には
どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

具体的なコードがないのが申し訳ないですがタッチ位置(右側か左側か)で分岐させるのはどうでしょう？